# Function return object

Tags: macros

I would like to create custom function to create objects.
Let me explain better, consider the following code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border={12pt,12pt}]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

    % Min/Max
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\Min}{1.5}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\Max}{2.0}
    % Tick distance
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\XTickDistance}{
        (\Min - \Max) / (10 - 1)
    }

    \begin{axis}[
    hide axis, scale only axis, height=0pt, width=0pt, % hide axis
    colormap/jet,
    colorbar sampled,
    colorbar horizontal,
    point meta min=\Min,
    point meta max=\Max,
    colorbar style = {
        samples = 9,
        height = 0.5cm,
        width = 8cm,
        xtick style = {draw=none},
        xticklabel style = {
            text width = 2.5em,
            align = center,
            /pgf/number format/.cd,
                fixed,
                fixed zerofill,
                precision = 2,
            /tikz/.cd
        },
        xtick distance=\XTickDistance,
    }
    ]
    \addplot [draw=none] coordinates {(0,0)};
    \end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

this will create a simple colorbar between *1.5* and *2.0* using the colormap *jet*.
I would like to create a function (named *customFunc*) that when invoked return a colorbar between two value, so the code will be just:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border={12pt,12pt}]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \customFunc{1.5, 2.0}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The real code of *customFunc* would be in a different file

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basically just do

```
\newcommand\MakeMeAColorbar[2]{ <the code that generates the colorbar> }
```

and add `#1` and `#2` where you have the min and max values. The `[2]` means that the macro has two default arguments, and `#1`/`#2` refer to those. Use it as

```
\MakeMeAColorbar{1.5}{2}
```

Of course you can put the whole `\newcommand` in a separate file, e.g. `MyMacros.tex`, and have `\input{MyMacros}` in the preamble.

Complete example:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border={12pt,12pt}]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\newcommand\MakeMeAColorbar[2]{%
    % Min/Max
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\Min}{#1}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\Max}{#2}
    % Tick distance
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\XTickDistance}{
        (\Min - \Max) / (10 - 1)
    }

    \begin{axis}[
    hide axis, scale only axis, height=0pt, width=0pt, % hide axis
    colormap/jet,
    colorbar sampled,
    colorbar horizontal,
    point meta min=\Min,
    point meta max=\Max,
    colorbar style = {
        samples = 9,
        height = 0.5cm,
        width = 8cm,
        xtick style = {draw=none},
        xticklabel style = {
            text width = 2.5em,
            align = center,
            /pgf/number format/.cd,
                fixed,
                fixed zerofill,
                precision = 2,
            /tikz/.cd
        },
        xtick distance=\XTickDistance,
    }
    ]
    \addplot [draw=none] coordinates {(0,0)};
    \end{axis}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\MakeMeAColorbar{1.5}{2}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

## Position

To set a specific position, you need a third argument as well. For example if you want the coordinate to be the first argument, you add

```
at={(#1)}
```

to `colorbar style`. Optionally add an `anchor` as well, to determine which part of the colorbar should be placed at that coordinate.

Complete code below. Note that there is a small vertical offset, the colorbar is placed a bit lower than it should be, and I'm not sure why that happens.

This time use it as `\MakeMeAColorbar{<coordinate>}{<min>}{<max>}`. If you want the `<coordinate>` to be an optional argument, change the first line of the definition to

```
\newcommand\MakeMeAColorbar[3][0,0]{
```

and use it as `\MakeMeAColorbar[<coordinate>]{<min>}{<max>}` or `\MakeMeAColorbar{<min>}{<max>}` depending on whether you want to specify the coordinate or not.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\newcommand\MakeMeAColorbar[3]{%
    % Min/Max
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\Min}{#2}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\Max}{#3}
    % Tick distance
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\XTickDistance}{
        (\Min - \Max) / (10 - 1)
    }

    \begin{axis}[
    hide axis, scale only axis, height=0pt, width=0pt, % hide axis
    colormap/jet,
    colorbar sampled,
    colorbar horizontal,
    point meta min=\Min,
    point meta max=\Max,
    colorbar style = {
        at={(#1)},anchor=center,
        samples = 9,
        height = 0.5cm,
        width = 8cm,
        xtick style = {draw=none},
        xticklabel style = {
            text width = 2.5em,
            align = center,
            /pgf/number format/.cd,
                fixed,
                fixed zerofill,
                precision = 2,
            /tikz/.cd
        },
        xtick distance=\XTickDistance,
    }
    ]
    \addplot [draw=none] coordinates {(0,0)};
    \end{axis}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]

\MakeMeAColorbar{current page.center}{1.5}{2}
\fill (current page.center) circle[radius=5pt];

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @yellowhat Updated answer.