# tikzpicture: Position object from \newcommand

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros

how can I position an object from \newcommand?

Let's consider my [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/332428/115489), for example, I want to position a new colorbar (*\MakeMeAColorbar*) to the page center, the code should be:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node at (current page.center) {\MakeMeAColorbar{1.5}{2}};       
\end{tikzpicture
```

But doesn't work.

Thanks

Comment: If you add `overlay` option to [Torbjørn T. answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/332446/1952) and compile it twice the color map is placed in `current page.center`.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand where to add `overlay`option.

Comment: Answered by Torbjørn T. [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/332446/115489).